# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы в MySQL

Tags: кодировка, cp1251, mysql

Создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `poisk_post` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`url` varchar(500) NOT NULL default '',
`title` varchar(500) NOT NULL default '',
`im` varchar(500) NOT NULL default '',
`description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL default '',
`keywords` varchar(1000) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)DEFAULT CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci;
```

Сам скрипт имеет кодировку ЮТФ8

код:

```
$title[1]=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $title[1]);
$description[1]=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $description[1]);
$keywords[1]=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $keywords[1]);
$url=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $url);
$pic=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $pic);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'login', 'pas', 'arashvg_poisk');
$db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO  `poisk_post` (`id`, `url`, `title` , `im` , `description`, `keywords`) VALUES ('', '".$url."','".$title[1]."','".$pic."','".$description[1]."','".$keywords[1]."')");
```

Смотрю в БД, вместо кирилицы сплошные знаки вопроса!
http://vkcontakte.pp.ua/121212.JPG

Как можно исправить?

**Вопрос решил простым добавлением строки:**

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем ты создаешь в 1251, а потом перекодируешь в утф8 ? Не логичнее сразу все в утф8 держать?

Comment: разве это так важно? 

пробовал переводить скрипт в кодировку 1251, убирал из него все iconv, но в базу всеравно идут знаки вопроса!

Comment: попробуй SET NAMES utf-8 заюзать